# OSX - how to change NSButton title color

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

My project  have button as well as check box with default title color black i want to change color of title to red

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and rewrite your question. Add some code, add some explanation, show what you tried so far.

Comment: i want to change just font color of button title

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSButton how to color the text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109964/nsbutton-how-to-color-the-text)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code to set the button title color in a controller:

```
 NSColor *color = [NSColor greenColor];
 NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
 [style setAlignment:NSCenterTextAlignment];
 NSDictionary *attrsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
 color, NSForegroundColorAttributeName, style, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, nil];
 NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
 initWithString:@"Title" attributes:attrsDictionary];
 [self.button setAttributedTitle:attrString];
```

may be this is all you want.

Comment: using above code, on click title gets removed, xcode 8.1 , osx 10.11