# How to style a NSButton?

Tags: xcode, macos, xamarin.mac

I want to make my buttons to look nice & stylish through out of my application :) , i tried some ways but those are not perfect for ex : if i set background color to my button , its not showing effect when i click it :( .

I like to set background color, height, width, text color , text font size & attributes and more.......

Can any one guide me to go for right approach please , you can see screenshot below that i am using buttons in my sample.

[image]

Comment: Do these answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109964/nsbutton-how-to-color-the-text http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017468/change-background-color-of-nsbutton

Comment: @jtbandes can i get button highlight color if i click on that ?